# Looking to simplify this code due to it being very repetitive

Tags: excel

I have a code that just enters text (which varies) into a cell, runs another macro, and then removes the text. Rather than repeating the same code and just changing what is entered (Highlander, NX, ES,...) is there a way I can simplify this to make it cleaner and easier to update if I want to add another variable. (I have a lot of selects, I plan on removing those once I can simplify and narrow this down)

```
Sub EnterSheet()
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Highlander" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Sienna_HV" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Corolla_Cross" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Camry_1" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Camry_2" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "ES" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Corolla" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Tundra" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Tacoma" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "NX" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "RAV_4" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Avalon" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "RX_350" & .Value
            With .Characters(1, 8).Font
        Call Copy
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Range("B1").ClearContents
    End With
End With
Sheets("Data Consolidation").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Store the words in an array and loop that?

Comment: Would this work even if I am looking to have the variables pasted into the same cell one after another?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. I sense your architecture needs more work but hard to advise without context.

Comment: @findwindow This helped and I was able to simplify it by a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub EnterSheet()
    Dim Vehicles As Variant
    Dim model As Variant
    Vehicles = Worksheets("Models-Features").Range("F3:F60").Value

    For Each model In Vehicles
        Worksheets("Overview").Range("B1").Value = model
        Call Copy
    Next model

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to add models, list them in cells and store that in your array. That way, you don't have to modify the code each time.